# Circles in UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uikit

I would like to modify this custom page control to draw circles for the unselected dots. Here's the current look:

[image: Image 1]

and here's my code:

```swift
public class PageControl: UIPageControl {
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    private var remainingDecimal: CGFloat = 0
    private var selectedColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    private var unselectedColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Public Properties
    public var dotRadius: CGFloat = 3 {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    public var dotHeight: CGFloat = 6 {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    public var dotSpacings: CGFloat = 7 {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    public override var numberOfPages: Int {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    /// Currently selected page.
    /// The first page is 1 and not 0.
    public override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            reset()
        }
    }
    public override var pageIndicatorTintColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            .clear
        }
        set {
            unselectedColor = newValue ?? .clear
        }
    }
    public override var currentPageIndicatorTintColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return .clear
        }
        set {
            selectedColor = newValue ?? .clear
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Public Functions
    // swiftlint:disable all
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
          guard numberOfPages > 0 else { return }
          for index in 0 ... numberOfPages {
              guard index != selectedIndex + 1 else { continue }
              let previousCirclesX = CGFloat(index) * (dotSpacings + (dotRadius * 2))
              var percentageWidth: CGFloat = 0
              var originX: CGFloat = previousCirclesX
              var barColor: UIColor = selectedColor
              switch index {
              case selectedIndex:
                  percentageWidth = dotRadius * 2 + ((dotRadius * 2 + dotSpacings) * (1 - self.remainingDecimal))
                  print("selected width: \(percentageWidth)")
                  barColor = between(selectedColor, and: unselectedColor, percentage: remainingDecimal)
              case selectedIndex + 2:
                  percentageWidth = dotRadius * 2 + ((dotRadius * 2 + dotSpacings) * (self.remainingDecimal))
                  originX = previousCirclesX - percentageWidth + dotRadius * 2
                  barColor = between(unselectedColor, and: selectedColor, percentage: remainingDecimal)
              default:
                  percentageWidth = dotRadius * 2
                  print("unselected width: \(percentageWidth)")
                  barColor = unselectedColor
              }
              barColor.setFill()
              let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: .init(x: originX,
                                                               y: 0,
                                                               width: percentageWidth,
                                                               height: dotHeight),
                                            cornerRadius: dotRadius)
              bezierPath.fill()
          }
      }
    // swiftlint:enable all
    public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let spacesWidth = CGFloat(numberOfPages) * dotSpacings
        let dotsWidth = CGFloat(numberOfPages + 1) * (dotRadius * 2)
        return .init(width: spacesWidth + dotsWidth, height: dotRadius * 2)
    }
    public func setOffset(_ offset: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) {
        print("Setting offset for page: \(self.currentPage)")
        selectedIndex = Int(offset / width)
        remainingDecimal = offset / width - CGFloat(selectedIndex)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let width = scrollView.bounds.width
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let pageIndex = Int(offset / width) % numberOfPages
        let newOffset = offset.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: width * CGFloat(numberOfPages))

        setOffset(newOffset, width: width)
        currentPage = pageIndex  // Update the currentPage to the new page index
        setNeedsDisplay()        // Request the page control to redraw itself
    }
    // MARK: - Private Functions
    private func reset() {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    private func between(_ color1: UIColor, and color2: UIColor, percentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        let percentage = max(min(percentage, 100), 0)
        switch percentage {
        case 0: return color1
        case 1: return color2
        // swiftlint:disable large_tuple
        default:
            var (red1, green1, blue1, alpha1): (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
            var (red2, green2, blue2, alpha2): (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
            guard color1.getRed(&red1, green: &green1, blue: &blue1, alpha: &alpha1) else { return color1 }
            guard color2.getRed(&red2, green: &green2, blue: &blue2, alpha: &alpha2) else { return color2 }
            return UIColor(red: CGFloat(red1 + (red2 - red1) * percentage),
                           green: CGFloat(green1 + (green2 - green1) * percentage),
                           blue: CGFloat(blue1 + (blue2 - blue1) * percentage),
                           alpha: CGFloat(alpha1 + (alpha2 - alpha1) * percentage))
        }
        // swiftlint:enable large_tuple
    }
}
```

I tried using `ovalIn` but no luck. I want perfect circles when (let's assume it's on page 1) it's in the middle. dots from left and right should be circles.

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you want a circle with roundedRect & cornerRadius, then the radius of the circle needs to be the radius of the corner.

Comment: @Larme could you clarify?

Comment: `let round = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGPoint(x: a, y: b, width: r*2, height: r*2), cornerRaidus: r)` should make a circle. Or with `UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGPoint(x: a, y: b, width: r*2, height: r*2))` as stated in the doc of the method, if the rect is a square, then it's a perfect circle.